# Flippant in RoR project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in front-end web development.
I am using flippant.js for flipping the dialogue.

```
<div id="overlay-box" class="overlayBox">
  <a class="closeBtn" onClick="closePop()">X</a>
  <button id="flipCard">Flip</button>
  <div class="content" ></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var front = document.getElementById("overlay-box")
    var  back_content = "
    <div class = 'overlayBox' style='top: 50.5px; left: 338px; display: block;'>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <a class = 'closeBtn' onClick = 'closePop()'>Y</a>
      <button id = 'closeCard'>Back</button>
      <div class = 'content'></div>
  </div>"

var  back

document.getElementById("flipCard").addEventListener('click',function(e){
    back = flippant.flip(front, back_content,'card')
    document.getElementById("closeCard").addEventListener('click',function(e){
        back = back.close();
    })
})
```

But the flippant plug-in asks for back_content rather than full HTML file.

I want to override that but facing a problem.

I tried to change the flippant.js file where it was taking content and converting that into HTML whereas the front document was not converted.

I am able to use it but then I will have to write my all HTML code in back_content variable which is ugly design.

I also tried to give HTML document directly by $(HTML_file).html but still no success.

The other problem is when I am giving all the HTML in the variable then it is not calling the js classes and all styling code also

Please suggest how to use flippant plug-in.
Thanks in advance

For flippant.js code refer to its github page https://github.com/mintchaos/flippant.js/blob/master/flippant.js